# Strange yellow indicator behavior when step run a sub

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a sub like this in worksheet event :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Or Selection.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim rgPrice As Range

Set rgPrice = Range("B6", Range("B24").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 2)

If Not Intersect(Target, rgPrice) Is Nothing Then
    If frmDaftarHarga.Visible = True Then
        If InStr(frmDaftarHarga.cbByNamaByTgl.Value, "Nama") Then
            frmDaftarHarga.PopLB_ByNama
        Else
            frmDaftarHarga.PopLB_ByTgl
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ""
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

When the frmDaftarHarga already shown/loaded and the yellow is at `If frmDaftarHarga.Visible = True` line, after I hit F8, the yellow goes to  `If InStr(frmDaftarHarga.cbByNamaByTgl.Value, "Nama")` ... I continue F8, the yellow goes either to `frmDaftarHarga.PopLB_ByNama` or `frmDaftarHarga.PopLB_ByTgl`

But when the frmDaftarHarga not shown / not loaded yet and the yellow is at `If frmDaftarHarga.Visible = True` line, after I hit F8, instead the yellow goes directly to `MsgBox ""`, it goes to the frmDaftarHarga UserForm_Initialize .

So it execute the UserForm_Initialize until finish (but not showing the Userform), then the yellow goes to `MsgBox ""`. I hit F8, then it show the blank msgbox.

My next try is changing the `MsgBox ""` line into `frmDaftarHarga.Show vbModeless` and put a stopper here (the red dot).

I Step run the sub (the userform is not showing / not loaded), and again it execute the UserForm_Initialize first then it stop at the red dot `frmDaftarHarga.Show vbModeless`. After I hit F8 again, it directly show the userform without going to the UserForm_Initialize.

I thought that after `If frmDaftarHarga.Visible = True` - because there is no userform shown, the yellow should go directly to `frmDaftarHarga.Show vbModeless` / `MsgBox ""` without going into the UserForm_Initialize ? What am I missing here ?

Any kind of respond would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: its because `.visible` is a property of the form, before VBA can know the form is visible or not, it has to load it first, hence the `initialize` event will be fired.

Comment: you can use `Load frmDafterharga` to preload the form, before checking the `visible` property, but it will fire `initialize`